# I want to create Label & MenuItem in cocos2dx 3.0 with custom font

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I want to create menu item & Label  with title & give color to its title in cocos2dx 3.0

For Label m using

```
LabelTTF *designInfoLabel;

if(temp == 1){
   designInfoLabel = LabelTTF::create("App", "Helvetica", 15, Size(545, 32), TextHAlignment::CENTER);
}
else{
   designInfoLabel = LabelTTF::create("App", "Helvetica", 13, Size(545, 32), TextHAlignment::CENTER);
}

designInfoLabel->setPosition(100,100));
this->addChild(designInfoLabel);
```

but this code has lot of warnings also I want to set colour for text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelTTF` and `CCMenu` are deprecated, please use `Label` and `Menu` classes instead:

```
Label *designInfoLabel;

if(temp == 1){
   designInfoLabel = Label::createWithTTF("App", "Helvetica.ttf", 15, Size(545, 32), TextHAlignment::CENTER);
}
else{
   designInfoLabel = Label::createWithTTF("App", "Helvetica.ttf", 13, Size(545, 32), TextHAlignment::CENTER);
}

designInfoLabel->setPosition(100,100));
this->addChild(designInfoLabel);

Menu *buttonsMenu = Menu::create(supportMenuItem, nullptr);
buttonsMenu->setPosition(Vec2(0.0, 0.0));
this->addChild(buttonsMenu, 1);
```

To set color for the label, you can call `Label::setTextColor(const Color4B &color);` function. For example:

```
designInfoLabel->setTextColor(Color4B::BLACK);
```

or set the RGBA directly like:

```
designInfoLabel->setTextColor(Color4B(0, 0, 0, 0));
```

Comment: How to create menuitem now

Comment: @Swastik The cpp-test folder under the cocos2d-x project already contains some official sample codes showing how to use the v3.x APIs. The sample code for creating menuItems is: https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-x/blob/v3/tests/cpp-tests/Classes/MenuTest/MenuTest.cpp

Comment: m using the same way, also included font in info.plist but its nt taking it

Comment: @Swastik I don't understand your question. Do you mean `Label::createWithTTF` not working? But if you're using TTF, why do you have to include font in info.plist? That doesn't make sense.